# Checksum errors indicative of hard drive failure

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have an old hard drive. I tried installing two things, PyTorch and Nvidia CUDA (large archive files) and both times the installation failed. When I checked the errors, both times it said the checksum of the downloaded files did not match the desired checksums.

How can I make sure it's a hard drive failure? Or, is there possibility it's something else?

Answer (score 1):

While a failing HDD can not be entirely ruled out, it seems rather odd that two just-downloaded files were corrupted in the few minutes needed to write/read them.
To completely excluded your HDD, run `smartctl --all </dev/yourdisk>` both before and after downloading/installing application, and check if the relative SMART values (ie: `Offline_Uncorrectable`, `Current_Pending_Sector`, `UDMA_CRC_Error_Count`, etc) increase between runs.

That said, it is way more probable that files were corrupted during download, maybe from your internet provider / local router / whatever. Finally, I would check your RAM is error-free running `memtest86` for at least 2 hours.

Comment: Unlikely to be internet. HDD, as far as I can tell, none of those value changed before after iinstall attempt. I know for a fact that the RAM has errors. So, given the scenario, you think the faulty RAM is highest culprit?

Comment: Well, sure: if you *know* that RAM has errors, you can not trust *anything* on this computer.